# Export of local file for dynamodb with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, amazon-dynamodb

I need to read an Excel spreadsheet, generate a unique field from it, create an id to save to the database,

I can export data from an xlsx file to dynamodb with this script, but I am unsuccessful when this file is too large; You can limit the reading of the file into parts without modifying or dividing it into parts.

```
var xlsx = require('xlsx');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

   const controller = {};

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var table = "Table";

    controller.export = (req, res) => {

        var wb = xlsx.readFileSync("data/sample.xlsx", { cellDates: true })
        var ws = wb.Sheets["FIT"]
        var data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws)

        var NewData = data.map(function (record) {
            record.NEW_ID = record.CD_EMPRESA + "_" + record.LOC_INI "_" + record.LOC_FIM;

            return record;
        });

        for (let index = 0; index < NewData.length; index++) {

            var params = {
                TableName: table,
                Item: {
                    "NEW_ID": NewData[index].NEW_ID,
                    "CD_EMPRESA" : NewData[index].CD_EMPRESA,
                    "LOC_INI" : NewData[index].LOC_INI,
                    "LOC_FIM" : NewData[index].LOC_FIM,
                    "ID_ATIVO" : NewData[index].ID_ATIVO,
                }
            };

            docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error", params, err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Success", params);
                }
            });

        }
        res.status(200).json();
    };

    return controller;
};
```